# Apache Ignite Query Cursor getAll is very slow

Tags: java, performance, ignite

I have 200 caches loaded into a single data region. Among that I have a 
customerCache which has 300K records. It has many indexed fields, including 
customer number.

When I query using **SQLFieldsQuery** on this particular cache (where 
condition has just customer number = ?), it takes around **280ms** to query a 
customer!

On detailed analysis, I found that, **SQLFieldQueryCursor.getAll()** is 
consuming 99% of the time (Getting cache instance and query execution is 
completing at nano second to 1 ms range). Is there any way to tune 
cursor.getAll()  or any alternate way to get data from cursor.

**More info**

I have annotated customer number with @Id, so assuming they were indexed and all queried fields were annotated with @QuerySqlField

Cache Configuration is as below:

```
dataRegionCfg.setInitialSize(8L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
dataRegionCfg.setMaxSize(8L*1024*1024*1024);
dataRegionCfg.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
dataStorageCfg.setDataRegionConfigurations(dataRegionCfg);
dataStorageCfg.setPageSize(4096);
customerCacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<>("customerCache");
customerCacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(CustomerKey.class, Customer.class);
customerCacheConfig.setReadThrough(false);
customerCacheConfig.setAtomicityMode(ATOMIC);
customerCacheConfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL);
```

My query was :

```
select customerName,customerId from CustomerMaster where customerNumber = ?;
```

Please provide some tips to improve the performance or let me know if I am 
missing something here.

Comment: Please provide exact cache configuration including indexes, as well as full original query within a snippet.

Comment: @alamar I have updated the question with requested items.

Comment: Can you provide sources for `CustomerKey` and `Customer`? I have strong suspicion that you don't actually have index on `customerNumer` since your key is `CustomerKey` and you should be declaring it with `@QuerySqlField(index=true)`

Comment: Can you also paste the full output of query `EXPLAIN select customerName,customerId from CustomerMaster where customerNumber = ?`?

Comment: My CustomerKey just have a UUID field and I have not indexed that field. But I have indexed my Customer Model that has customer number. Should I index key class field also?

Comment: Also is the cache.query() just returning references and actually are the results fetched in cursor.getAll() ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alamar for pointing the right way. My jar deployed in server node missed the index = true option.

Also ignite does not expect indexing in key class. Again, the performance won't improve by increasing number or indices, just like H2.